# How to write a static python getitem method?

Tags: python, static, operator-keyword, magic-methods

What do I need to change to make this work?

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def __getitem__(val):
        return "It works"

print A[0]
```

Note that I am calling the `__getitem__` method on the type `A`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When an object is indexed, the special method `__getitem__` is looked for first in the object's class. A class itself is an object, and the class of a class is usually `type`. So to override `__getitem__` for a class, you can redefine its metaclass (to make it a subclass of `type`):

```
class MetaA(type):
    def __getitem__(cls,val):
        return "It works"

class A(object):
    __metaclass__=MetaA
    pass

print(A[0])
# It works
```

---

In Python3 the metaclass is specified this way:

```
class A(object, metaclass=MetaA):
    pass
```

Comment: @ups: metaclasses are specified in a different way in Python3. I've added code to show how, above.

Answer (score 25):

Python 3.7 introduced [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__).

```py
class A:
    def __class_getitem__(cls, key):
        return "It works"

print(A[0])
```