# Python static dictionary in class that supports item assignment

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, static-members

I have a class that contains a static dictionary:

```
class MyClass:
    my_dict = {}
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        MyClass.my_dict[self.name] = []
    def __call__(self, data):
        MyClass.my_dict[self.name].append(data)
```

Whenever I want to update the dictionary, I have to use `MyClass.my_dict[key]`, but I'd like the class itself to support item assignment so I can just use `MyClass[key]` to do the same thing.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Have you looked at overriding - `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` ?

Comment: @Jon Clements - Can you do that to a class itself or only to an instance?

Comment: Only to an instance...

Comment: I found a relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187932/how-to-write-a-static-python-getitem-method

Answer (score 5):

So, here's what I ended up doing:

```
class MyClassType(type):
    my_dict = {}
    def __getitem__(cls, key):
        return cls.my_dict[key]
    def __setitem__(cls, key, value):
        cls.my_dict[key] = value
    def __str__(cls):
        return cls.my_dict.__str__()
    def iteritems(cls):
        return cls.my_dict.iteritems()

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyClassType
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        MyClass[self.name] = []
    def __call__(self, data):
        MyClass[self.name].append(data)
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use your code but I does not work..even with putting the metaclass=MyClassType as a parameter of MyClass