# python getter and setter in dict style of static class

Tags: python, class, static

Tell me what is wrong here ?

```
class GetCounter:

    @classmethod
    def add_counter(cls, name):
        setattr(cls, name, GetCounter(name))

    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        return getattr(cls, name)

    # obj wise
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.counter = 0
        self.timestamp = datetime.now()


GetCounter.add_counter('account_info')
counter = GetCounter['account_info']
```

I get

```
counter = GetCounter['account_info']
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

# this works
GetCounter.account_info.counter
```

I am trying to have a one class that will manage all my counters with a dict like access (dynamic naming).

Solved:
[How to write a static python getitem method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187932/how-to-write-a-static-python-getitem-method)

thanks.

Comment: Why not just have a dictionary keyed on (for example) 'account_info' where the associated values are instances of some "counter" class?

Comment: `__getattr__` is the wrong method if you want to support indexing (like `counter['foo']`). You need to implement `__getitem__`.

Comment: solved with __class_getitem__